# Can I fix ceiling fan in this existing outlet?

Tags: receptacle, ceiling-fan

I had a chandler light in dining area (first floor - no attic access) where I want put a ceiling fan. I am not sure the existing outlet box can hold the weight of the new ceiling fan. Here is the photo. Can someone please check and advise?[image]

Comment: Can you post a closeup of the back of the junction box please?

Comment: Certainly looks like a plastic junction box which will not hold the weight of a fan. I think you need to pull out this box and install a fan-rated box.

Comment: Yeah, it is not metal. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What is the  mfgr and model of fan? I installed some Hunter fans (5-bladed sealed bearings) that had instructions for hanging the fan from the joist next to the box. If the joist is adjacent to the box and the box is small enough, the box is hidden by the large shroud. Check the instructions for your fan. Of couse, this might put the fan noticeably off center of the room. If you want to hang the fan from a box at the location of this box, then you would have to remove this one and put in a fan rated box.

Comment: Thanks Jim. It's Hunter Kaplan ceiling fan.

Comment: The Hunter fans I installed had special specification long wood screws with washers that would screw through ceiling drywall deep into the ceiling joist to hold the bracket for the fan. This allows keeping the original ceiling box since the fan is not suspended from the box.